# Nginx config, if location not

Tags: nginx

My config

```
    rewrite /silosy /produktsiya/silosy last;

    location /go/ {
        rewrite /go/http\:/(.*) http://$1 permanent;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Now rewrite for "/go" and "/silosy" doesn't work because: "if (!-e $request_filename)" is using. How can I add location restriction like this:

```
location [not (go|silosy)] {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

How will "not" be looking in nginx location?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how will looks "not" in location, But I found solution:

```
    rewrite ^/silosy /produktsiya/silosy permanent;
    rewrite ^/go/(.*) http://$1 permanent;

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `if (!-e $request_filename)` into `location /` block. It is for the *unmatched*.